# Finding the correct boundary conditions to a specific problem

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, parametric-functions

I want to reproduce the following problem in the figure:[image]

$$\phi''+c\phi'\sqrt{m^2\phi^2+\phi'^2}+m^2\phi=0$$

where $\phi=\phi(x)$ with $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$,  $c=\sqrt{3/2} \ $ and $m=0.2$.

Albeit the authors use "random initial conditions", none values that i try are fitted with this solution. A simple example where $\phi(0)=m\sqrt{2/3} \ $ and  $\phi'(0)=0 \ $ do not exposes the expected result:

Renaming $\phi(x)$ as $y(x)$:

```
(*INPUT*)
MP = 1;
m = 0.2 MP;
c = Sqrt[3/2];
x1 = -40;
x2 = 40;

(*ODE*)
s2 = NDSolve[{y''[x] + 
     c (Sqrt[m^2 y[x]^2 + y'[x]^2]) y'[x] + 
     m^2 y[x] == 0,y[0] == m/c, y'[0] == 
    0}, y, {x, x1, x2}]

(*Plot*)
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{y[x], y'[x]} /. s2], {x, x1, x2},
 PlotRange -> Full,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 AxesLabel -> {Style["\[Phi]", 15, Black], 
   Style["\[Phi]'", 15, Black]}]
```

I know that is not a exclusive numeric code problem, but i will glad to understand the exact initial condition that solve adequately this issue.

Comment: I see no problem when running your code. It also works for `phi'!<0.01`. It gets better if you increase your integration domain, 40 is a bit far from infinity :P

Comment: I try @tsuresuregusa. These initial conditions lead to a singular point at x==−42.5864.

I want a solution that  $\phi \to 0  \Rightarrow \phi' \to 0 \ $ and  when $\phi \to \pm \infty  \Rightarrow \phi' \to \mp m/c \ $ .

Comment: y'[0] == .005 and x2 = 4000 reaches 0, or something similar to the figure you show at least. Then y[0] == 2 m/c, y'[0] == 1 approach the m/c line for a bit. Now, it doesn't make sense to set x1 = -40 if your initial conditions are for 0. With x1=0 the singularity disappears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you give the initial condition at a different point that your lower limit of the integration.

If you change x1 by 0 things seem to work:

```
(*INPUT*)MP = 1;
m = 0.2 MP;
c = Sqrt[3/2];
x1 = 0;
x2 = 4000;

(*ODE*)
Clear[s2]

Table[s2[i] = 
   NDSolve[{y''[x] + c (Sqrt[m^2 y[x]^2 + y'[x]^2]) y'[x] + 
       m^2 y[x] == 0, y[0] == RandomReal[{-10, 10}], 
     y'[0] == RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, y, {x, x1, x2}], {i, 10}];

(*Plot*)
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[{y[x], y'[x]} /. s2[i], {i, 10}], {x, x1, x2}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["\[Phi]", 15, Black], 
   Style["\[Phi]'", 15, Black]}]
```

[image]

[image]